# Cannot determine GraphQL input type for argument when it has ArgsType

Tags: prisma, typegraphql

Given following code:

```
@Query(() => CompanyTalentRoster)
  async findCompanyTalentRoster(
    @Args() args: FindFirstCompanyTalentRosterArgs
  ): Promise<CompanyTalentRoster | null> {
    const data: Prisma.companyTalentRosterFindFirstArgs = {
      where: {
        ...args.where,
        // TODO: companyId: ctx.companies[0].id,
      },
      orderBy: args.orderBy,
    };
    return this.companyTalentRosterService.findFirst(data);
  }
```

`FindFirstCompanyTalentRosterArgs` is autogenerated by typegraphql-prisma with @ArgsType decorator.

I getting the following error:

```
[2023-03-14T17:04:41.044] [ERROR] [TSED] - CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError:
Cannot determine GraphQL input type for argument named 'args' of 
'findCompanyTalentRosters' of 'CompanyTalentRosterResolver' class. Is the value, 
that is used as its TS type or explicit type, decorated with a proper decorator 
or is it a proper input value?
at Function.getGraphQLInputType (/Users/backend/node_modules/type-
graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:560:19)
```

If I change the decorator in the generate file to `InputType` it suddenly works correctly. How can I make it work without customizing autogenerated typings?